# Disable apache's auto directory "/" completion

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm in the following situation:

I have a directory named `test` at the top level of my site. When I request `http://mysite.com/test`, apache automatically adds a trailing slash and gives me `http://mysite.com/test/`. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: don't do that. why would you do that?

Comment: Is this a Unix question? Apache's "/" is not a Unix-dependent feature, correct? I believe this question belongs on Serverfault.

Comment: @Stefan: probably, but do you have enough points to close a question yet?
unix.stackexchange is depressing as it is… no need to bicker about one of the least problems.

Comment: @hop being offtopic doesn't make it less depressing. IMO the real problem is we have a broken community, with ubuntu having its own SE. I really hope the ultimate vote is to merge.

Comment: @Stefan ubuntu se should merge with superuser. have you seen the questions tehre?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to fix missing slashes, but the most likely one in your case is the [Directory Slash Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) of mod_dir, which by default is on.

I'd recommend not to change that configuration, though, because there are good reasons for its existence.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
actually I want to use mod_rewrite to catch everything so I think it'll be ok

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: i found it first ;)